# Elixir structs default value from same module

Tags: elixir

Don't know how to create a struct where the default value is from a function within the same module. Heres my example:

```
defmodule Poker.Deck do
  alias Poker.Deck.Card

  @values [:a, :"2", :"3", :"4", :"5", :"6", :"7", :"8", :"9", :"10", :j, :q, :k]
  @suits [:spades, :clubs, :diamonds, :hearts]

  def new do
   (for x <- @values, y <- @suits, do: %Card{value: x, suit: y})
   |> Enum.shuffle
  end

  # Putting this at the top or bottom still doesn't solve the problem...
  defstruct deck: __MODULE__.new, used: [], in_hand: []
end
```

When compiling it returns the following:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/poker/deck.ex ==
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Poker.Deck.new/0
    Poker.Deck.new()
    lib/poker/deck.ex:14: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:657: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) src/elixir.erl:163: :elixir.erl_eval/2
    (elixir) src/elixir.erl:156: :elixir.eval_forms/4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the fact that defstruct simply defines a function `__struct__()` which returns a map containing a `__struct__` key to accomplish this:

```
defmodule Poker.Deck do
  alias Poker.Deck.Card

  @values [:a, :"2", :"3", :"4", :"5", :"6", :"7", :"8", :"9", :"10", :j, :q, :k]
  @suits [:spades, :clubs, :diamonds, :hearts]

  def new do
   (for x <- @values, y <- @suits, do: %Card{value: x, suit: y})
   |> Enum.shuffle
  end

  def __struct__() do
    %{__struct__: __MODULE__, deck: __MODULE__.new(), used: [], in_hand: []}
  end
end
```

Running this gives me a fresh shuffled deck for each new instance of `%Poker.Deck{}`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. If defstruct did the same thing, why wouldn't it compile? Is it executing the `__MODULE__.new()` at compile time?

Comment: I think it's a bug in the defstruct implementation, but I haven't spent the time to figure out precisely why it fails. It seems like the issue might be around how it builds the struct definition itself, by first quoting the values, then building a map with all the fields and storing the result in a module attribute, which is then referenced in `__struct__()`. My guess is that when it does that, it's calling the function, which doesn't exist yet at that stage of compilation. In any case, it would be worth opening an issue for on GitHub for sure, just so José is aware of it.